# second Test case is not call in testng maven project with selenium

Tags: java, windows, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to automate Justdial.com with the TestNG Maven project. My first test case "VerifyFlightClickTest" is working fine it is clicking on the Flight option by justdial the home page.
After that, I created a new class for my second test searching the flight for my input(e.g - New Delhi to Jaipur on 04-April-2022).
the test case name is "Validation_Flight_Booking" and the class name is "VerifyFlightBook".
help me to find out what I am doing wrong

only one test is pass

------- This code is for driver location ------

```
package com.Automation.GenericUtils;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;


public class DriverUtils {
    
        static WebDriver driver;
        
        public static void createDriver()
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\ss49655\\eclipse-workspace\\JustDial_Shubham\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
            
            ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions();
            option.addArguments("start-maximized");
            option.addArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
            option.addArguments("--disable-notifications");// Disabling any notifications
            driver=new ChromeDriver(option);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();    
        }
        
        public static WebDriver getDriver()
        {
            if(driver== null) {
            createDriver();
            }
            return driver;
        }

    }
```

------- This code is for Base page ----

```
package com.Automation.Pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import com.Automation.GenericUtils.DriverUtils;

public class BasePage {
     WebDriver driver;

    public BasePage()
    {
        driver=DriverUtils.getDriver();
        PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);
        
    }
}
```

----- This code is for Home page (JustDial home page)------

```
package com.Automation.Pages;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

public class HomePage extends BasePage{

    @FindBy(xpath="//*[@id=\"hotkeys_text_25\"]")
    private WebElement KeyClick;
    
    public void clickOnFlights() {
        KeyClick.click();
    }
}
```

-------- this code is for base test---

```
package com.Automation.Test;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;


public class BaseTest {
    WebDriver driver;
    
    @BeforeMethod
    
    public void setUp() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        com.Automation.GenericUtils.DriverUtils.createDriver();
        
}
    /*@AfterMethod
    public void Close()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }*/
}
```

----------- This code is for clicking on the flights page -----

```
package com.Automation.Test;

import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.Automation.GenericUtils.DriverUtils;
import com.Automation.Pages.HomePage;

public class VerifyFlightClickTest extends BaseTest {
    @Test
    public void ValidateFlightClick () throws InterruptedException
    {
        DriverUtils.getDriver().get("https://www.justdial.com/");
    
    
        HomePage hp= new HomePage();
        
        hp.clickOnFlights();
}}
```

****** This code is for flight book page after clicking on the flights in home page----

```
package com.Automation.Pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

public class FlightBookPage extends BasePage{


    @FindBy(xpath="//input[@placeholder='Type Departure City']")
    private WebElement DC;
    
    
    @FindBy(xpath="//li[text()='New Delhi, IN - Indira Gandhi Airport (DEL)']")
    private WebElement Select_Airport;
    
    public void DepartureCity(String username)
    {
        DC.sendKeys(username);
        }
@FindBy(xpath="//input[@placeholder='Type Departure City']")
    private WebElement CityName1;
    
    @FindBy(xpath="//li[text()='New Delhi, IN - Indira Gandhi Airport (DEL)']")
    private WebElement airPort1;
    
    @FindBy(xpath="//input[@placeholder='Type Destination City']")
    private WebElement clickOnDestinationCity;
    
    @FindBy(xpath="//input[@placeholder='Type Destination City']")
    private WebElement typeDestinationCity;
    
    @FindBy(xpath="//li[text()='Jaipur, IN - Sanganeer (JAI)']")
    private WebElement selectDestinationCity;
    
    
    // SELECT DATE 
    
    @FindBy(xpath="//input[@placeholder='Select Date']")
    private WebElement dateClick;
    
    @FindBy(xpath="//*[@id=\"second_2022-04-04\"]")
    private WebElement myDate;
    
    //CLICK ON SEARCH BUTTON
    
    @FindBy(xpath="//input[@value='SEARCH']")
    private WebElement search;
    
    public void clickOnDeparture() {
        DC.click();
    }
    public void typeName(String username) {
        CityName1.sendKeys(username);
    }
    
    public void selectName() {
        airPort1.click();
    }
    
    public void DestinationCity() {
        clickOnDestinationCity.click();
    }
    
    public void typeName2(String username) {
        typeDestinationCity.sendKeys(username);
    }
    
    public void selectdescity() {
        selectDestinationCity.click();
    }
    
    public void clickOnDate() {
        dateClick.click();
    }
    
    public void MyDate() {
        myDate.click();
    }
    
    public void btnsearch() {
        search.click();
    }
    
}
```

---

This is for test flight book page ----

```
package com.Automation.Test;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.Automation.GenericUtils.DriverUtils;
import com.Automation.Pages.FlightBookPage;
import com.Automation.Pages.HomePage;

public class VerifyFlightBook extends BaseTest {

    
    
    @Test
            

    public void Validation_Flight_Booking() throws InterruptedException
    {   
        
        FlightBookPage fb=new FlightBookPage();
        
        fb.clickOnDeparture();
        fb.DepartureCity("New Delhi");
        /*fb.SelectAirport();
        fb.DestinationCity("Jaipur");
        fb.Destination();
        fb.Selectdate();
        fb.Date();
        fb.Flight_search();*/
        
        
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        fb.selectName();
        fb.DestinationCity();
        fb.typeName2("Jaipur");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        fb.selectdescity();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        fb.clickOnDate();
        fb.MyDate();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        fb.btnsearch();
        
        
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: How are you running it?

Comment: I am running it by testng.xml file <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
    <classes>
     
      <class name="com.Automation.Test.VerifyFlightClickTest"/>
      <class name="com.Automation.Test.VerifyFlightBook"/>
    
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->

Comment: I can't see where you've specified which URL to go to for the second test. Were you expecting it to use the same browser window as the first test?

Comment: yes! I am expecting that first it open the URL and then click on the flight button and then as written in the second test case in the same windows it will do some action with the help of the second test case in the search flight windows type the destination and departing city name select the date and click on search flight. but after executing the first test case it remains the same

Comment: TestNG generally makes no guarantees about the order tests will run, or that they'll even run in the same thread.  You can't expect any information to be passed from one test to another - that is, the two tests will generally run completely independently of each other.  If you have dependent test steps like this, I would recommend coding them into the same test method.

Comment: ok Dawood ibn Kareem
 :)